# create special keyboard shortcuts using C#

Tags: c#, keyboard-shortcuts, eventhandler

I want to create a special keyboard shortcut.
I thought maybe to create a Windows forms app that the UI is empty, after turning on the pc, the program will open automatically, and will wait to the special shortcut.
I thought maybe to create Event Handler for the shortcut(For example if 'E' and "M' are pressed), and than it will do what I will set up in the code.
I'm facing a hardship in creating this EventHandler.
Can you give me some tips or share your opinion?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options for running your Windows Form at startup.

1.You can use the Windows Task Scheduler to run the program at startup. In your bin/Release or bin/Debug, get the scheduler to run your YourFormName.exe program when Windows starts. How-To Geek has a pretty good tutorial on how to do this.
2.You could also use the Windows Startup folder. Make a shortcut to the If you want it to run for just the current user, the path to the folder is

```
`C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`
```

and for all users it is

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Start-up
```

3.Then just drop a shortcut to your form (the same one I mentioned above) in one of these folders.
Another option is to register it in the Windows registry

```
using System.IO
namespace {
     {
public partial class TestForm:Form{
RegistryKey reg = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run","true");
public TestForm(){
reg.SetValue("MyApp",Application.ExecutablePath.ToString());
InitializeComponent();
                 }
            } 
      }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! maybe you can help me with another problem I'm facing. I succeeded to do that after the user press the F5 something will happen but only inside the form, how can I do it to work outside the form. I want that after the F5 is pressed some text will be sent using SendKeys.Send. How can I make it work outside the form?